# Command buttons fail to render

Tags: visualforce

I have a very simple Visualforce page which is meant to override the View functionality of a custom object.

```
<apex:page standardController="My_Custom_Object__c" showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
<apex:form >

    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:sectionHeader title="{!My_Custom_Object__c.Name}" subtitle="My Subtitle" />

    <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">

        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:outputField value="{!My_Custom_Object__c.User_Lookup__c}" />
            <apex:outputField value="{!My_Custom_Object__c.CreatedById}" />
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:outputField value="{!My_Custom_Object__c.CreatedDate}" />

            <apex:outputField value="{!My_Custom_Object__c.Text_Field__c}" />
            <apex:outputField value="{!My_Custom_Object__c.Opportunity_Lookup__c}" />
            <apex:outputField value="{!My_Custom_Object__c.Cross_Object_Formula__c}" />
            <apex:outputField value="{!My_Custom_Object__c.Text_Area__c}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="both" rendered="true">
            <apex:commandButton id="edit_button" action="{!edit}" value="Edit" rendered="true"/>
            <apex:commandButton id="delete_button" action="{!delete}" value="Delete" rendered="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

For whatever reason the `<apex:commandButton />` tags fail to render.  I have full permissions to both edit and delete this record.  If I view the standard page layout, the buttons are available to me.  The VF Page will save without issue.

I cannot figure why the buttons won't render.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user viewing the form have a profile with Edit/Delete access to our custom object?
StandardController actions on Visualforce pages respect permissions.

Comment: I have full permissions to both edit and delete this record. If I view the standard page layout, the buttons are available to me.